# Overriding the custom style on a proprietary Qt5 application

Tags: qt, dark-mode

I'm running KDE Plasma 5.22 on Gentoo using Kvantum for my application theme engine. I'd like to use the application [Chaotica](https://chaoticafractals.com), which is a fractal rendering suite that is far superior to most others, but unfortunately is proprietary and therefore difficult to modify. It uses Qt5 for its UI, but it has a custom theme that I can't seem to override, and it's a serious issue for usability because I have worse-than-average eyesight and its dark theme and small text make it really hard for me to see what I'm doing (it does not have interface zoom functionality). Take a look at how an application (KeePassXC) adhering to my theme looks in comparison to Chaotica:

[image: KeePassXC screenshot]
[image]

I found out that you can supposedly use the -style option to override the style set by the software, but that isn't working for me. If I run `chaotica -style kvantum`, it says:

```
QApplication: invalid style override passed, ignoring it.
 Available styles: Windows, Fusion
```

But even if i run it as `chaotica -style Fusion` it doesn't change the style. One thing that I was wondering might be influencing that is the fact that the application ships with its own copies of Qt libraries, so I changed `qt.conf` to:

```
[Paths]
Prefix=/usr
Libraries=/lib64
Plugins=/lib64/qt5/plugins
```

These directories have all the same files as the folders shipped with Chaotica containing its Qt libraries, so that should work. However, running the program from console with that qt.conf gives me the error message:

```
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not find the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in ""
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.
```

And then it just never launches.

The file libQt5XcbQpa.so.5, which the software ships with, also exists in /lib64, and libqxcb-glx-integration.so exists in the shipped plugin folder as well as the one that I put in qt.conf, so I really have no idea why it's saying that. I don't have any idea what to do beyond that - anyone else know how I could force it to use my system theme, or at the very least a larger font?

Comment: Chaotica has a forum ... why are you asking here?

Comment: It's a general question about an issue with the way Qt is implemented here, which I'm sure applies to other proprietary Qt-based applications - the issue is not likely with Chaotica, but this method of implementing Qt on Unix. Chaotica's forum is both very inactive and not focused on Linux/Unix.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to point your app to Qt5 plugins the other way:

```
QT_QPA_PLATFORM_PLUGIN_PATH=/usr/lib64/qt5/plugins chaotica -style Fusion
```